# if @@trancount > 0 commit tran issue

Tags: sql, sql-server, jtds

When I'm executing `sp_who2` on my database I see that process by `SPID` is `RUNNABLE` and its `CPUTime` is equal to 2147483647.

`DBCC INPUTBUFFER(SPID`) returns me that the last query is

> 'IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 COMMIT TRAN'.

I'm using jDTS driver to connect to Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2.

Why `CPUTime` is so high? Does it mean that some transactions weren't closed or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the maximum value for a signed int32 and seems to be a default which Microsoft chose to stand in for an unknown/yet-to-be-determined CPU Time value. I have been excluding these from my performance related queries of sys.sysprocesses for years.

Try using sys.dm_exec_requests instead. It seems to handle these values for you as I've never seen this occur when using it.